# How to remove the last character from an NSMutableString

Tags: iphone, nsmutablestring

Iam adding some text content to nsmutablestring in the form of dictionary format and again that every dictionary is split by ","(commos). But when getting this total string its displays  (,) to string of ending. So how to remove that ","(commos) in that mutable string.

Please guide me if any one knows

Thanking in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how you need to remove character from NsmutableString....

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange([concatedstring length]-1,1);
[concatedstring replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 7):

Doing that way, you keep the mutable property of your string:

```
[mutableString setString:[mutableString substringToIndex:[mutableString length]-1]];
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove the last character of a string you can write:

```
string = [string substringToIndex:[string length] - 1];
```

Comment: Nope. you're changing a mutable object to an immutable one.

Comment: Only one that worked for me! Strange, but the error is strange as well, as the object I'm trying to change is a NSMutableString -_- thks  @Luke Pullman